# Set graphics editor in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, graphics, android-studio-arctic-fox

How do you set the graphics editor in Android Studio Arctic Fox? In previous versions of Android studio, I was able to right click on an image displayed in Android Studio and select "Jump to external editor" and the editor that was specified in settings would open to display the image.  The setting was lost and I cannot figure out where to set the editor in this new version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting to create external tool in the AS Settings.

[image]

In the step 3, browse your preferred app to handle your file which is passed in the step 4.
The step 4 allows you to choose lots of arguments but $FilePath$ is the common argument I think.

Later, you can choose External tools to open your expected file.

[image]